# Python regex and several named groups found in line

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract some specific information from CFT (tool to copy files from any OS to another OS). 
I parse the output of the command "cftutil listcat content=full"

I want to extract dates, hours, number of records in local and remote file...

For examples I get lines like

```
Records      NRECS    = 49016                 Records  NREC     = 49016
```

where I want to extract the value after NRECS or NREC

or lines like

```
Begin date   DATEB    = 15/02/2019   End date DATEE    = 15/02/2019
Begin time   TIMEB    = 12:18:21.05  End time TIMEE    = 12:18:23.16
```

where I want the date and hour for begin and end of transfer

My regex only gets the first match in the line

my program

```
import re
reg = r"""
(^.*)DIRECT\s+=\s(?P<direct>[A-Z]{4})
|
(^.*)DATEE\s+=\s(?P<date_end>\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})
|
(^.*)DATEB\s+=\s(?P<date_deb>\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})
|
(^.*)TIMEB\s+=\s(?P<hour_deb>\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{2})
|
(^.*)TIMEE\s+=\s(?P<hour_end>\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{2})
|
(^.*)NREC\s+=\s(?P<nb_records_loc>\d+)
|
(^.*)NRECS\s+=\s(?P<nbrecords_rem>\d+)
"""
pat1 = re.compile(reg,re.VERBOSE)
with open("CFT_FULL.TXT","r") as a:
    source = a.read().split('\n')
    for i, lin in enumerate(source):
        if (" FNAME" in lin or " NFNAME" in lin):
            print '\n'.join(source[i+1:i+2])
        m = re.search(pat1, lin)
        if m is not None:
            print m.lastgroup, "---> ", m.group(m.lastindex)
        if "JOBNAME" in lin :
            print lin,'\n'
```

Edit: partial output

```
date_end --->  06/02/2019
hour_deb --->  08:19:48.63
nb_records_loc --->  139
```

But I should have

```
date_deb --->  06/02/2019
date_end --->  06/02/2019
hour_deb --->  08:19:48.63
hour_end --->  08:19:49.52
```

Thanks for any hint

edit

Eventually, the following code works fine

`m = re.search(pat1, lin)
        if m is not None:
            for x in re.finditer(pat1,lin):
                print x.lastgroup,"--->", x.group(x.lastindex)`

it prints

`date_deb ---> 06/02/2019
date_end ---> 06/02/2019
hour_deb ---> 08:19:58.64
hour_end ---> 08:19:58.75
nbrecords_rem ---> 62
nbrecords_loc ---> 62`

Comment: Please show us expected output (exactly) and actual output.

Comment: added, see my edit

Comment: Remove all `(^.*)`s. See it here https://regex101.com/r/Qkx2ek/1

Comment: Looks like key-value extraction. You may read the file in with `source = a.read()` and then use something like `re.findall(r'(\w+)\s*=\s*(\S+)', source)` and then build the output.

Comment: revo, I removed like you said, but it makes no difference

Comment: I'm not sure about the coding stuff but for sure you shouldn't have those greedy dots at beginning. That's the first step to take.

Comment: `this|that|those` will stop as soon as it finds `this` or `that`.  There are ways to code what you are attempting as a regex, but really, a simple parser might be less of a headache.

Comment: @revo 's suggestion seems to work about fine given the available information (with the caveat that re.search() matches a single occurence per line and therefore misses the second Records in a line) : https://ideone.com/i0UDmK

Comment: to triplee, I already have code with simple string extraction that works, I thought named groups of a regex would get me only the data I want

Answer (score 1):

Please change your regex to ,

```
reg = r"""
DIRECT\s+=\s(?P<direct>[A-Z]{4})
|
DATEE\s+=\s(?P<date_end>\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})
|
DATEB\s+=\s(?P<date_deb>\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})
|
TIMEB\s+=\s(?P<hour_deb>\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{2})
|
TIMEE\s+=\s(?P<hour_end>\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{2})
|
NREC\s+=\s(?P<nb_records_loc>\d+)
|
NRECS\s+=\s(?P<nbrecords_rem>\d+)
"""
```

Also, as re.search() returns the first occurrence of a match, i would suggest to use, re.finditer(). Eg. for the below string:

```
Begin date   DATEB    = 15/02/2019   End date DATEE    = 15/02/2019
Begin time   TIMEB    = 12:18:21.05  End time TIMEE    = 12:18:23.16
```

The expected output will be,

```
>>> for x in re.finditer(pat1,above_string):
    print(x)


<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(13, 34), match='DATEB    = 15/02/2019'>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(46, 67), match='DATEE    = 15/02/2019'>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(82, 104), match='TIMEB    = 12:18:21.05'>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(115, 137), match='TIMEE    = 12:18:23.16'>
```